# Why there is no EF Core OfType(Type type) method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I currently use EF Core 3.0.
So, I want to realize TPH model data selection through  the base table requesting. 
Let's see the example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public int Base {get;set;}
}

public class Foo : BaseClass
{
   public int FooMember {get;set;}
}

public class Bar : BaseClass
{
  public int BarMember {get;set;}
}

public DbSet<BaseClass> dbSet {get;set;}
```

And I want to implement code like this:

```
var getInheritedSet = dbSet.OfType(typeIStronglyNeed);
```

But I can only do something like this:

```
var getInheritedSet1 = dbSet.OfType<Foo>;
var getInheritedSet2 = dbSet.OfType<Bar>;
```

Could you explain why EF Core 3.0 has no `OfType(Type type)` but only `OfType<TType>()`?

And the second question - how is it possible to get inherited data types from DbSet?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: Yes, but how will this allow me to cast to an inherited types filtering/selecting from `DbSet<BaseClass>`?

Comment: We cannot answer *why* framework does not provide a method. Can you provide more context for the usage scenarios you are trying to address? I'm asking because there might be a solutions to your scenarios not based on `Type` - for instance, `dbSet.Where(e => e is Foo)` and other combinations of `is` and `cast` operators.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, I want to have an ability to realize universal method which allows me to get dynamically typed data objects from database. For example, I have a remote service which could be asked by me for different kind of users retrieving from database. So, without dynamic casting I should create 2 methods on the remote side for retrieving 2 different types of Users. With `OfType(TType type)` I could realize only one passing required Type as an argument through the DTO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic method `OfType<T>` is a standard LINQ method which EF Core supports.

There is no standard `OfType(Type)` method and EF Core designers didn't find a reason of implementing such custom EF Core specific extension.

But it's not hard to be implemented. TPH (and other future database inheritance strategies) are supported in LINQ to Entities queries by `is`, `as` and `cast` operators. So what you need is the equivalent of

```
Where((BaseClass e) => e is some_type)
```

Such expression cannot be created at compile time, but can easily be created using the `Expression` class methods (in particular [Expression.TypeIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeis?view=netframework-4.8)) like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OfType<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Type type)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var body = Expression.TypeIs(parameter, type);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

> And the second question - how is it possible to get inherited data types from DbSet?

EF Core metadata is exposed through `DbContext.Model` property. You can use `FindEntityType` to get the `IEntityType` describing the entity type

```
var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(BaseClass));
```

and now there are a lot of available methods regarding inheritance like `GetDerivedTypes`, `GetDerivedTypesInclusive`, `GetDirectlyDerivedTypes`, `GetConcreteDerivedTypesInclusive` etc. The last one can be used to retrieve the whole TPH hierarchy excluding the abstract types. And also `GetDiscriminatorProperty` and `GetDiscriminatorValue` to get the discriminator column name, type and value for each entity in the TPH. For instance

```
var discriminatorProperty = entityType.GetDiscriminatorProperty();
var typeInfo = entityType
    .GetConcreteDerivedTypesInclusive()
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Type = t,
        DiscriminatorValue = t.GetDiscriminatorValue()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Oh, cool, thank you! Earlier I found a mediate solution using ".Where(e => EF.Property<string>(b, "Discriminator") == PassedType)", but it's not an elegant and wide solution. I'll try to implement my methods using information I get from you. Thanks!